# Overriding virtual method with generics and constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to override the [`DbContext.Set<TEntity>()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx).

It's signature is:

```
public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
```

First I tried this:

```
public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
{
    return base.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

... but I get the error:

> The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set()'

... so I then tried specifiying it was a reference type:

```
public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity: class
{
    return base.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

... and I now get:

> Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation methods are inherited from the base method, so they cannot be specified directly.

... and if I take it away, I'm back to the first error.

So what does the C# compiler want me to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well this is lame... I was using version 6.0.0 of Entity Framework.

In 6.0.0 (after digging through the [history of the project on Code Plex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs), I found out that `Set<TEntity>()` ***wasn't*** `virtual` back then.

Shame the compiler couldn't say that, rather than sending me round the houses.

Anyway, updating Entity Framework to 6.1.x (where it *is* `virtual`), solved the problem;

```
Update-Package EntityFramework
```

Comment: Nice find. A tip if you encounter a problem like this again: you can always right-click "Set" in `base.Set` and choose "Go to definition" in Visual Studio, even if you don't have the Entity Framework source code installed locally. There, you would have seen that the method wasn't virtual. And agreed that the compiler should give useful messages.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post an entire class.

Here is how I am using and I can compile without any problem.

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

Please make sure that you are using latest Entity Framework (6.X)

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track; as soon as I removed the rest of the code in the class, the compiler changed it's message to "`Set<TEntity>()` is not `virtual`; see my answer for what happened next... I don't have the rep to +1, but I don't think this is worthy of a -2 :(.

Comment: why  my answer goes down? do you want us to help?

Comment: Make sure that you are using a right version. I am using EF 6.X

Comment: I don't have the reputation to up-vote or down-vote :(. It wasn't me! :(.

Comment: They have even introduced IDbContext so that you can automate Unit testing.

Comment: I know it might not be you there are alwyas some mischief around. You can mark this as answer if it helps.